# How to know the byte code size of a Java method

Tags: java, methods, jvm, bytecode

Would like to take a look at the byte code size of a method to see how far it is to the maximum length(64KB). How could I do that?

Comment: Why is this important? What use case can get near to this limitation?

Comment: I'm joining @ppeterka66 in agogness. Anyone trying to get a method that was 64k in byte code would be sacked way before they managed it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I don't usually follow clean code by the exact numbers, but 64k method is something I never felt stressing unlike the 640k in the DOS days... Lets say, I'd be astonished to find such an issue in real code.

Comment: I've been sat here trying to think how I could get something that size to actually compile, never mind run. That's a LOT of source code. :)

Comment: @Tony There's one method in the JRE itself that is 29kb. It's more likely then you'd think.

Comment: There's a few people who wrote that thing who shouldn't have...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `javap -c YourClassName` - that will show you the byte offsets of each instruction for each method.

Alternatively, to do this programmatically, I strongly suspect [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) will help you out.

Comment: Note that the offset of the final instruction won't take into account the length of the final instruction. But in most cases this is just a return which is 1 byte, so you can just add 1.